# Sharing structs across multiple packages

Tags: go

Lets say we have a client server scenario, in this situation both the server and the client speak to each other using a common message structure. So, one use `struct` to define that message structure, something like this

```
type Message struct {
    SenderId int
    Content string
    AuthCode string
}
```

Now to avoid repeating yourself and having a `Message` structure in both the client package and server package, what is the GoWay to address this problem ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three different approaches:

1. Keeping both server and client in the same package, as does the
   [`http`](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/net/http) package.
2. Creating separate packages (say `message`, `common`, `types`, ...) and adding your shared structures there, as does [`etcd`](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/tree/master/pkg)
3. Putting them in the `server` package and importing that in the `client` package. For example, the [`x/net/websocket`](https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/websocket) package imports `net/http`.

It's really a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Lets say i go with door number three, could you elaborate on how to do that ? Or better yet just share an example. And thanks for your answer

Comment: Done, added the example. :-)

Comment: What example? Am I missing something?